# How to bind elements in backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a small backbone class:

```
view = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "click textarea" : "doSomething"
    },
    doSomething : function() {
        var textarea = $(this.el).find('textarea')
        // I would like to just call, this.textarea, or this.elements.textarea
    }
});
```

Ideally I would like to be able to access my textarea through a variable instead of having to search the element every time. Anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe i am under thinking it but how bout giving the textarea a class or id and target specifically when needed,

or create a sub view that generates the textarea

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#main',
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var subview = new SubView();
        this.$('form').append(subview.el);
        this.$('form').show();
    },
});

var SubView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'textarea',
    id: 'whateverId',
    events: {
        "click" : "doSomething"
    },
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    doSomething : function(event) {
        var textarea = $(event.target);
        // or var textarea = $(this.el);
    },
    render: function(){
        return $(this.el);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers get you the reference that you need, but if you really need a handle to the textarea, then you can do something like this:

```
view = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.myTextareaElement = $(this.el).find('textarea')
  }
  events: {
    "click textarea" : "doSomething"
  },
  doSomething : function() {
    // use this.myTextareaElement ...
  }
});
```

Comment: This might or might not work dependent if you are adding the text area in the render function or passing an already rendered DOM element as el into the view.

Answer (score 0):

pass the event as the argument and then use the event target

```
view = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
      "click textarea" : "doSomething"
    },
    doSomething : function(event) {
      var textarea = $(event.target);

    }

});
```

Comment: but what if i want to access my Textarea from a different function that is triggered by a different event? know what i mean?

Comment: I am going to add this as another answer since its not formatting like i expected